# UISwitch does not show up on UITableView (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios8, uiswitch

I have a UITableView and I have added a UISwitch on a static cell. (The table has sections and static cell). I added an IBOutlet

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *useWifiSwitch;
```

and an action using the interface builder in my storyboard.

However the UISwitch does not show when the application is running. I haven't added anything in the viewDidLoad. Anybody has a clue?

Comment: Autolayout? Try rotating the device and see if it shows up.

Comment: Are you using autolayout? Have you checkd UITableViewCell's heigth? Is UISwitch hidden?

Comment: Autolayout indeed. that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the universal layout in the `Interface Builder` is 600x600 but the device isn't, your `UISwitch` is probably off screen. You can fix it by adding `Constraints` to the `UISwitch`.

Give it a fixed height and then top, bottom and trailing constraints as recommended by the `InterfaceBuilder`.